# What should I do with misaligned sink pipes

Tags: pipe, sink, pvc

I tried to fix a clogged sink and found the problem was much more complex: I have to replace the sink waste too. And after I installed the newly bought waste, the pipes failed to align. 
[image: Vertically misaligned pipe]

I think it's because the new waste is a little bit too long, 'pushing' the pipe it's connecting down a little bit further.

I am thinking maybe I can get an extension to fit in between? Or I can cut off a part of the vertical pipe coming from the ground. Problem with the second option is I have to work out how much I need to cut, and what's the best tool for the job.

Are there any other options? Thanks.

Comment: Normally the tailpiece coming down from the sink drain can be adjusted or cut to length. If you loosen the white plastic nut (below the gray nut, below the sink drain) can you remove the pipe that goes down from the drain and cut it to length?

Comment: I don't think I can, it's a wholepiece made of metal.

Comment: I mean the white plastic part -- if you cut that down could you still attach it to the tail piece? But also, metal tailpieces are also designed to be cut to length (with a hacksaw).

Comment: Or I can take it to the shop and ask them to cut it for me...

Comment: I wouldn't cut the tail piece, the end with the nut is a little bit larger, if I cut it short I risk break it and the nut may not hold tight.

Comment: So if I want to cut the metal part, how long should I cut off? How can I work out the correct number.

Comment: New question. If you adjust the gray nut, can you lower the upper plastic piece down and then retighten it in a lower position around the tailpiece (coming down from the sink drain)? If so, then you have some flexibility on the height of the upper piece, and you can cut & re-attach the pipe that rises from the floor to reduce its height, then adjust this around the tailpiece to match it.

Answer (score 2):

This looks all wrong. It looks like you have installed an adjustable P-trap upside down. The upside down "U" shaped piece attached to the pipe coming from the cabinet floor is supposed to be under the sink strainer.

You need a proper tailpiece to attach to the strainer, which will come down into the "tall" end of the "U" shaped piece. The piece you now have attached to the strainer is supposed to be connected to the "short" part of the "U" shaped piece and runs horizontally to the pipe coming from the cabinet floor, where you will need a slip-joint elbow to connect them. Something more like this:

[image]

Please do it right and avoid "clamp-on" Fernco type connectors, as some have suggested. They always end up leaking.

Answer (score 0):

just cut horizontally across the pipe that projects up from the cabinet base.  cut it off about 3" up from the base, and then again about 2" up from the base.  you have essentially removed a 1" section of pipe.  then install a 1-1/4" fernco flexible coupling over the stub (up from the cabinet) and the remainder of the trap side stub.  tighten the two gear clamps and you are done.